# how to display all data on a webpage

Tags: php

I wrote this code to comment system on my webpage. But i want to keep showing all data on web page while another people do comment and see another people's comment

```
include 'connection.php';
        $con1= new connection();
        $db=$con1-> open();
        $qry= "INSERT INTO post (content) VALUES ('".$_POST["commentEntered"]."')";
        $db->exec($qry);
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {       

        if ($con1->query($qry) === TRUE) {
            echo "Your Comment Successfull Submited";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $qry . "<br>" . $con1->error;
        }


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM post';

    $q = $db->query($sql);

    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $con1->close();
        }
if ($_POST)
        echo "<h2> Your Comment Successfully Submitted</h2>  <br> ".$_POST['commentEntered']."<br>";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

after your `select`, inside your `if($_POST)` write this

```
while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
  foreach($row as $key=>$val){ 
     if (!is_numeric($key)) echo "<p>$key=>$val</p>";
  }
}
```

**EDIT** i'm not 100% sure you can close the connection and still do a ->fetch, (I *think* you can but i've never tried it) so you *may* have to move your connection close after this (but I *think* you'll be alright), also I am not sure if `setFetchMode` will return duplicate numbered keys or not so as a precaution I have filtered for them you may not need to